# Yii2 REST API PUT method with images

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, put

I am getting issue in `PUT` method of `YII2` rest api when I pass images otherwise its working fine. In `POST` request its working fine.

Below is my code

```
  /**
     * Funcion to update existing product by productID
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $post = $request->post();
        $params = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;
        print_r($params);
        die;
        $model = Product::findOne($id);
        $images = $model->uploadProductImages($_FILES);
        $post['images'] = implode(",", $images);
        $model->updateProduct($id, $post);
        return $post;
    }
```

When I try with images below is the output I get.

```
Array
(
    [-----------------------------16309270534592
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "name"

TESTP11APR
-----------------------------16309270534592
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sku"

SKUTESTP11APR
-----------------------------16309270534592
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="Koala.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

????
)
```

And I remove the image fields from swagger then proper data I get.
What will the issue.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides support for the HTTP PUT method used by some clients to store files on a server.

```
PUT /path/filename.html HTTP/1.1
```

The following code is in the [php documention](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) for uploading files via PUT:

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```